# Inject UserTransaction in Restful service using servlet filter

Tags: java, rest, servlets, ejb

I have an EAR application which contains JAVA project, EJB project, Web Project.

I have been using Restful service and accessing EJB by using JNDI lookup. And is there a way like, instead of EJB injection UserTransaction is injected to my Restful webservice, where Rest will act as servlet and i can inject my simple POJO class as UserTransaction with the help of servlet filters. I hope with this we can remove EJB Project.

Comment: By "Restful service" do you mean you're using JAX-RS?  By "inject my simple POJO class as UserTransaction" do you mean "inject an instance of my POJO class in the same way that the builtin UserTransaction object is injected"?  Does the solution actually need to servlet filters, or are you just suggesting a possible solution?  What version of Java EE are you using?  It sounds like you want to use CDI, which was introduced in Java EE 6 and allows arbitrary objects to be injected into EE components objects.  Otherwise, EJB is your only real option.

Comment: Yes. Am talking about JAX-RS, I felt like keeping UserTransaction adding it to http headers using servlet filters. where every full filling request pass through filters and UserTransaction begins and exiting filter will commit my transaction. If any failure i can roll back. Am using Java EE 6

Comment: I don't understand what you mean; how does UserTransaction relate to servlet filters?  It should work to use a filter to begin/end a transaction if that's the architecture you want to use.

Comment: Sorry, I thought, i could inject userTransaction Object into servlets and it can be used in Rest Impl. I hope i can't do this. I think i can achieve this with @Resource in my Implementation class